# C++ and the Perils of Double-Checked Locking : Workaround?

Tags: c++, c++03, double-checked-locking

I was reading a paper on "Perils of double check locking by Scott Meyers". http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf

The author gives reasons why the double check lock fails (page 3, section 4). I was thinking of ways to get around this problem without using C++11. Not that I don't want to use C++ 11 but just to see if it is possible to solve it without using functions such as std::call_once, etc

```
class Singleton {
public:
    static Singleton* instance();

private:
    static Singleton* pInstance;
    int someData_;
};


Singleton* Singleton::instance() 
{
    class SeqAssign{
    public:
        SeqAssign(Singleton*& pInst, Singleton* pNew):
        pInstance(pInst), pNewedInst(pNew){
        }
        ~SeqAssign(){
            pInstance = pNewedInst;
        }

    private:
        Singleton*& pInstance;
        Singleton*  pNewedInst;
    };

    if (pInstance == 0) { // 1st test
        Lock lock;
        if (pInstance == 0) { // 2nd test
            SeqAssign seq(pInstance, new Singleton);
        }
    }
    return pInstance;
}
```

Will the code in Singleton::instance() work in a multi-threaded environment as the order in which the constructor and destructor is called for the SeqAssign class is deterministic.

Comment: The workaround is "Don't use a singleton".

Comment: you are right, sometimes, singleton is called an anti-pattern and it is recommended to avoid it. Here the question is not singleton, it is about how to make double check locking work.

Comment: If you don't want C++11 stuff, don't tag the question as such. I retagged to `[c++03]`.

Comment: @Ram Not by any of the experts I know.  The almost universal consensus is that it's a useful pattern for a few specific uses (but that it can be horribly abused).

Comment: On the other hand, I've never understood what double checked locking brings to the singleton pattern.  It's easy to ensure that the singleton is constructed before entering `main`, and you really shouldn't be starting threads before entering `main`.

Comment: Actually, "before entering main" is kind of complicated since you often need to establish an order of things, and those 'before main' things pretty much happen in randomish order. I generally do a bit of both: I collect a list of "things to do" with priorities to establish the correct ordering before main, and work through that list early in main.

Comment: Singletons are helpful - just do not overuse them. 
My guess would be `Lock lock;` is not the same lock for different threads - you probably have to have common mutex for them in struct.

Comment: @Pawel:  Yes, lock is representative code. Also, this question is not to figure out singleton implementation. I would like to know how to make the double check lock work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The variable `pInstance` is accessed from more than one thread.  It
is modified.  The code has undefined behavior.  And I'm not sure what
you thing `SeqAssign` will do, since it doesn't introduce any additional
inter-thread sequencing.

There is no way to make double checked logging work in standard C++; all
of the solutions involve atomic variables (possibly implemented using
inline assembler) or thread local storage.

Comment: TLS and atomics are part of Standard C++ now. You might want to revise that to Standard C++03.

Comment: James, can you please elaborate why? Here, the destructor call is deterministic and it has to be at the end of the scope. Does C++ not guarantee RAII. If it does, by the same logic, should this not work ?

Comment: @Ram: It's not an observable side effect- that is, the optimizer is free to inline and shift it around.

Comment: @DeadMG The original poster asked about non-C++11.  I should have been specific that that was the standard I was referring to.

Comment: @Ram RAII only works within a single thread.  There's nothing to guarantee that other threads see the writes in the same order as they occur in the writing thread.

Comment: @DeadMG Not just the compiler.  The order values appear in global memory is not necessarily the order the store instructions appear in the compiler generated assembler.  Hardware does a lot of reordering today, and is why you need explicit synchronization even if you turn off all compiler optimization.